# Aggregating table via a loop

Tags: vba, loops, ms-access, aggregate-functions

I have a data table containing multiple shipments - table name "2 - Rates 0 Pre-Setup".
Example of data.

```
Country     POL            Volume
India       Mumbai         90
India       Mumbai         9
India       Nhava Sheva    3
India       Nhava Sheva    474
India       Tuticorin      19
India       Tuticorin      1352
Indonesia   Jakarta        1020
Indonesia   Jakarta        67
```

I need to aggregate this data based on the volume field into a new table to generate a template for the user, to look like below.

```
Country     POL            Volume
India       Mumbai         99
India       Nhava Sheva    477
India       Tuticorin      1371
Indonesia   Jakarta        1087
```

The code below works fine to copy the original table and generate the new "Test 1" table but am struggling to aggregate the data based on the Volume field.
Presumed sum(lane!Volume) but it errored.

```
Private Sub NewOceanFreight_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim lane As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb

Set lane = db.OpenRecordset("2 - Rates 0 Pre-Setup")
Set Test1 = db.OpenRecordset("Test 1")

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM [Test 1]"

    Do Until lane.EOF
        lane1 = lane![Country]
        lane2 = lane!POL
        lane3 = lane!Volume

        Test1.AddNew
        Test1![Origin Country] = lane1
        Test1![Origin Port] = lane2
        Test1![CBM] = lane3
        Test1.Update
    lane.MoveNext
    Loop
    lane.Close
    DoCmd.Requery
    End Sub
```

Apologies if this is a repeat but am new to VBA in Access and couldn't find an answer that worked for me from other posts, so any advice welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply run an aggregate query on your original table and if needed use a [make-table query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-make-table-query-96424f9e-82fd-411e-aca4-e21ad0a94f1b) to export results to a new table. No VBA is needed here. All can be done in the SQL query design.

```sql
SELECT t.Country, t.POL, SUM(Volume) AS Total_Volume
FROM [2 - Rates 0 Pre-Setup] t
GROUP BY t.Country, t.POL
```

With make-table action query using `INTO` clause

```sql
SELECT t.Country, t.POL, SUM(Volume) AS Total_Volume
INTO myNewTable
FROM [2 - Rates 0 Pre-Setup] t
GROUP BY t.Country, t.POL
```

Comment: was looking to use VBA as have a large number of similar queries that I wanted to remove to keep the file size down in order not to have temp tables. I will use your suggestion in meantime though. Thanks.

Comment: You can use VBA to automate these make-table SQL queries. Simply loop through tabledefs or querydefs and execute make-table actions on aggregate queries: `CurrentDb.Execute "SELECT * INTO mynewTable FROM myaggquery"`.

Comment: Great that works well much simpler to build. Much appreciated.